# How to add dropshadow effect for custom button?

Tags: uwp-xaml

I have made a custom style for my button like the following:

[button](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoI4pKdRYn8Knm-PFnLYIrPv8-rk)
I now want to add dropshadow for it. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to add dropshadow effect for custom button?

In general, we use `DropShadow` class to render control's shadow. You could refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.dropshadow?view=winrt-19041#examples).

And we could also use Windows Community Toolkit  Controls  [`DropShadowPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/dropshadowpanel) Control to approach like the following.

```
<controls:DropShadowPanel BlurRadius="4.0" ShadowOpacity="0.70"
                          OffsetX="5.0" OffsetY="5.0" Color="Black">
    <Image Width="200" Source="Unicorn.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
</controls:DropShadowPanel>
```